# Unit test to assert that a boolean has been changed when a scripts load event fires

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, onload

I have a script that loads `ckeditor.js` and once loaded it disables auto inline ..

```
var script = window.document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', 'ckeditor.js');
window.document.body.appendChild(script);
script.addEventListener('load', function() {
  CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
});
```

Is there a way I can `assert` that `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline` is set to `true` once the script's `load` event handler is triggered?

```
it('should ensure disableAutoInline is set to true when the ckeditor.js file is loaded in the browser', function() {
  window.CKEDITOR = {
    disableAutoInline: false
  };
  var ckeditorjs = window.document.querySelectorAll('[src=\'/ckeditor.js\']');
  expect(ckeditorjs.length).to.equal(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to actually trigger the `load` event on the `script` ..

```
var ckeditorjs = window.document.querySelectorAll('[src=\'/ckeditor.js\']');
window.CKEDITOR = {
  disableAutoInline: null
};
var event = new Event('load');
ckeditorjs[0].dispatchEvent(event);
expect(window.CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline).to.equal(true);
```

Comment: Your code may be correct but some comments about what's wrong in OP and how the answer fixes it is highly recommended.